# Django pluggable for managing currency accounts and transactions

Tags: django, currency, account

We are writing an application that requires users to have accounts with balances in dollars and points. Is there a pluggable django app already out there that will help us?

Answer (score 3):

There is an app called [python-money](http://code.google.com/p/python-money/).  It has some code to define a MoneyField in Django models, but our initial experiments with it showed some problems so we just switched to using regular [DecimalField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield).

[DecimalField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) is intended for currencies and I think this is best for your case as well because it doesn't sound like you need to maintain balances in multiple currencies.

**Edit:** Responding to additional requirements where transactions, account management etc. are needed.

Try [minibooks](https://secure.caktusgroup.com/projects/minibooks), especially taking notice of their [Ledger models](https://secure.caktusgroup.com/projects/minibooks/browser/trunk/ledger/models.py).

If this doesn't work I think you'll have to step outside of Django and try to incorporate something like [OpenERP](http://www.openerp.com/) or [Tryton](http://www.tryton.org/) (an OpenERP fork) into your Django app.

Comment: We need transaction histories.  So we need more than just a new type for currency amounts.  For example, we need something like a Transaction model, an CurrencyType model, and an Account model.